# remove special char from rows in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe...unable to remove the "-" char and trim it to the right "int" number for the cell:

```
    Branch   Market Company     Brand Name  MRP 2020-05-15 2020-05-19 2020-05-22 2020-05-26
1      USA      abc     xqz           A     165    180-190    170-180        170        170
2      USA      abc     xqz           B     165    180-190    170-180        170        170
3      USA      abc     xqz           C     100        120    110-120        120        120
4      USA      abc     xqz           D      95        110        100        100        110
5      USA      abc     xqz           E      59         70         70         70         70
```

want the following dataframe to plot a scatter plot with brand name in x-axis and MRP in y axis.

```
    Branch   Market Company     Brand Name  MRP 2020-05-15 2020-05-19 2020-05-22 2020-05-26
1      USA      abc     xqz           A     165        185        175        170        170
2      USA      abc     xqz           B     165        185        175        170        170
3      USA      abc     xqz           C     100        120        115        120        120
4      USA      abc     xqz           D      95        110        100        100        110
5      USA      abc     xqz           E      59         70         70         70         70
```

can you plz help. tried many codes, but unable to get the desired result/df.

Comment: What have you tried? Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html to find and replace the strings in series. Also, I think you need to find the average and not just getting the next int value after char `-`. Please provide code and complete example so that we can try and provide the solution

Comment: I was tring the following code for a specific column but getting an error: ``` df['2020-05-26'] = df['2020-05-15'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: x[1]), error msg: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
# extract the date columns
cols = [col for col in df.columns if '-' in col]

df[cols] = (df[cols].astype(str).stack()
     .str.extractall('(\d+)')
     .astype(float).mean(level=[0,1])[0]
     .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
      Branch  Market    Company    Brand    Name      MRP    2020-05-15    2020-05-19    2020-05-22    2020-05-26
--  --------  --------  ---------  -------  ------  -----  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
 0         1  USA       abc        xqz      A         165          92.5          87.5            85            85
 1         2  USA       abc        xqz      B         165          92.5          87.5            85            85
 2         3  USA       abc        xqz      C         100          60            57.5            60            60
 3         4  USA       abc        xqz      D          95          55            50              50            55
 4         5  USA       abc        xqz      E          59          35            35              35            35
```

Answer (score 0):

with `np.where` and `str.split`:

```
df['2020-05-15'] = np.where((df['2020-05-15'].str.contains('-')),
                            (df['2020-05-15'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(float) + df['2020-05-15'].str.split('-').str[1].astype(float)) / 2,
                            df['2020-05-15'])
df['2020-05-19'] = np.where((df['2020-05-19'].str.contains('-')),
                            (df['2020-05-19'].str.split('-').str[0].astype(float) + df['2020-05-19'].str.split('-').str[1].astype(float)) / 2,
                            df['2020-05-19'])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)** and **[`statistics.mean`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-statistics-mean-function/):**

```
import statistics

df['2020-05-15'] = df['2020-05-15'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: statistics.mean(list(map(int, x))))

df['2020-05-19'] = df['2020-05-19'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: statistics.mean(list(map(int, x))))
```

Output:

```
   Branch Market Company Brand Name  MRP  2020-05-15  2020-05-19  2020-05-22  2020-05-26
0       1    USA     abc   xqz    A  165         185         175         170         170
1       2    USA     abc   xqz    B  165         185         175         170         170
2       3    USA     abc   xqz    C  100         120         115         120         120
3       4    USA     abc   xqz    D   95         110         100         100         110
4       5    USA     abc   xqz    E   59          70          70          70          70
```